# ActiveAdmin show partial doesn't see the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, activeadmin

In ActiveAdmin 0.4.3, and Rails 3.2.2 I'm trying to customize the show screen of my Article mode

```
ActiveAdmin.register Article do

  show do
     render "show"
  end

end
```

And in app/views/admin/articles/_show.html.haml

```
%div= article.description
```

But whenever I try to show an Article I get:

```
NoMethodError in Admin/articles#show

Showing /Users/phishman/Sites/wisegrowth/app/views/admin/articles/_show.html.haml where line #1 raised:

undefined method `description' for <article></article>
:Arbre::HTML::Article

Extracted source (around line #1):

1: %div= article.description

Trace of template inclusion: /Users/phishman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activeadmin-0.4.3/app/views/active_admin/resource/show.html.arb

Rails.root: /Users/phishman/Sites/wisegrowth
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/views/admin/articles/_show.html.haml:1:in `_app_views_admin_articles__show_html_haml___3305533421865107600_2209712640'
app/admin/articles.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
app/middleware/flash_session_cookie_middleware.rb:17:in `call'
```

Can you please help me on this? It is getting me crazy!

In the console everything seems to be working fine and if I do:

```
a = Article.last
a.description
=> "my article description"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

`render :partial => "show", :locals => {:article => article }`

Comment: Yay! The issue stems from the partial not being able to access the `article`. You can use this technique to pass in other local variables too, but don't go crazy with it.